# Как заменить текст в docx в приложении ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, docx

Есть документ с содержимым вроде "Привет [[username]]". Нужно программно заменить "[[username]]" на свой текст не испортив форматирование и не используя word.

Comment: • https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK • https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core • https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi

Comment: Зачем закрываете? Нормальный вопрос же.

Comment: "Не используя Word" это что значит? ниже представлен код использующий COM офиса. Если Вы имели ввиду это, то курите в торону OpenXML, а так код работает, проверено.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик , я имел в виду чтобы можно было использовать веб приложение без установленного ворда.

Comment: если это файл docx, тогда распаковываем его как zip, ищем в xml файлах вхождение и меняем на свое, запаковываем как zip. Вроде так, вообще не нужен никакой openXML тогда... via топорный метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция, заменяющая текст в файле по регулярному выражению. Используется OpenXML

```
public static void SearchAndReplace(string document, string regex, string newText)
        {
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
            {
                string docText = null;
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
                {
                    docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                Regex regexText = new Regex(regex);
                docText = regexText.Replace(docText, newText);

                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    sw.Write(docText);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Добавить в `References` `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` и использовать `replace(string fileName, string findText, string replaceText)` из кода, приведенного ниже

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...

protected static void ReplaceWord(Word.Range range, object findText, object replaceText)
{
  object matchCase = false;
  object matchWholeWord = true;
  object matchWildCards = false;
  object matchSoundsLike = false;
  object matchAllWordForms = false;
  object forward = true;
  object format = false;
  object matchKashida = false;
  object matchDiacritics = false;
  object matchAlefHamza = false;
  object matchControl = false;
  object read_only = false;
  object visible = true;
  object replace = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
  object wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
  range.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                     ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceText, ref replace,
                     ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
  foreach (Word.Shape shape in range.ShapeRange)
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(shape.TextFrame.HasText).Equals(true))
      ReplaceWord(shape.TextFrame.TextRange, findText, replaceText);
}

public static replace(string fileName, string findText, string replaceText)
{
  Word.Application objWord = new Word.Application();
  try
  {
    Word.Document doc = objWord.Documents.Open(fileName);
    foreach (Word.Range range in doc.StoryRanges)
      ReplaceWord(range, findText, replaceText);
    foreach (Word.Section section in doc.Sections)
    {
      foreach (Word.HeaderFooter headerFooter in section.Headers)
        ReplaceWord(headerFooter.Range, findText, replaceText);
      foreach (Word.HeaderFooter headerFooter in section.Footers)
        ReplaceWord(headerFooter.Range, findText, replaceText);
    }
    doc.Save();
    object save = false;
    object missing = null;
    doc.Close(ref save, ref missing, ref missing);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
  objWord.Quit();
}
```

Comment: `catch (Exception ex)  {  }` - вот за такое руки отрывать надо

Comment: @PavelMayorov оставлено для творчества...

Comment: ваш пример к сожалению не подходит для asp.net приложения

Comment: -1 Не в коем случае не используйте Office COM для веб-сайтов. Там ужасная производительность и утечки памяти.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик Вот [официальный источник](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). Цитата: **"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."**